# Node-weighted steiner problem with few terminals

Tags: graph-algorithms, np-hardness, parameterized-complexity, fixed-parameter-tractable

Consider the node-weighted steiner problem:

> Input: a graph $G=(V,E)$, a set $T\subseteq V$ of terminals, a weight function $w: V\setminus T \to \mathbb{R}_+$.
>
> Output: a minimum weight subset $S \subseteq V\setminus T$ of vertices such that $G[T\cup S]$ is connected.

Is this problem polytime solvable when the number $|T|$ of terminals is a constant?

Comment: I was about to post this paper https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.21825 as a further answer to your question, and then I realized that you are an author xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An algorithm with a run-time of $n^{poly(k)}$ should be easy where $n = |V|$ and $k = |T|$. Think of an optimum solution which is edge-minimal. It will be a tree and one can see that the number of nodes with degree $\ge 3$ in this tree will be $O(k)$. We can guess those nodes $A$. Once we guess those nodes we create a graph on $A \cup T$ with edge-lengths between two nodes $u,v$ equal to the shortest node-weighted path between $u$ and $v$ in $G$ (we do not include the end points in this calculation). Then find a min-cost spanning tree in the resulting graph.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer is yes](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?oi=bibs&hl=en&cluster=8044686711250386358). There is a dynamic programming algorithm that runs in time $O^*(3^k)$. It is a generalization of Dreyfus and Wagner's well-known algorithm for Steiner tree.